# Convert PDF files to TIFF with python

Tags: python, pdf, tiff

How convert PDF files to TIFF images with python?

I have found solutions through arcpy and PythonMagick, but I think these libraries are not available for windows

Comment: Try https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pythonmagick